# Updating heroku pipeline environment variables

Tags: heroku, configuration, pipeline, heroku-pipelines

If I want to update environment config variables for a heroku app, I would run the following command:

```
heroku config:set FROM_EMAIL=$(FROM_EMAIL) --app=my-app
```

Say I have a pipeline which I would like to add the same environment variable. What would be the equivalent command to update my Heroku CI config variables.

I have had a look at all the available options to me by running:

```
heroku help pipelines
```

Nothing seems to facilitate this. I have looked at adding these environment variables to individual pipeline apps, but it does not change the pipeline settings.

I need to configure lots of different config variables and need to be able to do this via the command line, doing it manually would be too problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the option:

```
heroku ci:config:set FROM_EMAIL=$(FROM_EMAIL) --pipeline=my-pipeline
```

Comment: That adds something, because I can get them back with `ci:config`. But what about the review app configs? Any known solution for those? Referring to those in the "Config" tab of the pipeline directly, used when creating new review apps.